# How to calculate connections of the node in Spark 2

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following DataFrame `df`:

```
val df = Seq(
  (1, 0, 1, 0, 0), (1, 4, 1, 0, 4), (2, 2, 1, 2, 2),
  (4, 3, 1, 4, 4), (4, 5, 1, 4, 4)
).toDF("from", "to", "attr", "type_from", "type_to")

+-----+-----+----+---------------+---------------+
|from |to   |attr|type_from      |type_to        |
+-----+-----+----+---------------+---------------+
|    1|    0|   1|              0|              0|
|    1|    4|   1|              0|              4|
|    2|    2|   1|              2|              2|
|    4|    3|   1|              4|              4|
|    4|    5|   1|              4|              4|
+-----+-----+----+---------------+---------------+
```

I want to count the number of ingoing and outgoing links for each node only when the type of `from` node is the same as the type of `to` node (i.e. the values of `type_from` and `type_to`).

The cases when `to` and `from` are equal should be excluded.

This is how I calculate the number of outgoing links based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48171591/calculate-links-between-nodes-using-spark) proposed by user8371915.

```
df
  .where($"type_from" === $"type_to" && $"from" =!= $"to")
  .groupBy($"from" as "nodeId", $"type_from" as "type")
  .agg(count("*") as "numLinks")
  .na.fill(0)
  .show()
```

Of course, I can repeat the same calculation for the incoming links and then join the results. But is there any shorter solution?

```
df2
  .where($"type_from" === $"type_to" && $"from" =!= $"to")
  .groupBy($"to" as "nodeId", $"type_to" as "type")
  .agg(count("*") as "numLinks")
  .na.fill(0)
  .show()

val df_result = df.join(df2, Seq("nodeId", "type"), "rightouter")
```

Comment: _Of course, I can repeat the same calculation for the incoming links and then join the results. But is there any shorter solution?_ - grouping columns will be different so you should do separate aggregation and `join`.